# Upload file in struts2 from python requests.post

Tags: python, file-upload, struts2, python-requests

I have a jsp to upload a file in struts2 and works pretty well. But now I need upload a file from a external application i.e. python.

I tried this but I receive a error message.

**UploadFileAction.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.apache.struts2.util.ServletContextAware;
import com.appweb.FileUtil;
impoRt com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class UploadFileAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletContextAware{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4748500436762141116L;

@Override
public String execute(){
    System.out.println("File Name is:"+getFileFileName());
    System.out.println("File ContentType is:"+getFileContentType());
    System.out.println("Files Directory is:"+filesPath);
    try {
        FileUtil.saveFile(getFile(), getFileFileName(), context.getRealPath("") + File.separator + filesPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return INPUT;
    }
    return SUCCESS;

}

private File file;
private String fileContentType;
private String fileFileName;
private String filesPath;
private ServletContext context;

public File getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public String getFileContentType() {
    return fileContentType;
}

public void setFileContentType(String fileContentType) {
    this.fileContentType = fileContentType;
}

public String getFileFileName() {
    return fileFileName;
}

public void setFileFileName(String fileFileName) {
    this.fileFileName = fileFileName;
}

public void setFilesPath(String filesPath) {
    this.filesPath = filesPath;
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext ctx) {
    this.context=ctx;
}

}
```

**FileUtil.java**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileUtil {

public static void saveFile(File file, String fileName, String filesDirectory) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    File dir = new File (filesDirectory);
    if ( !dir.exists() )
       dir.mkdirs();

    String targetPath =  dir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName;
    System.out.println("source file path ::"+file.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("saving file to ::" + targetPath);
    File destinationFile = new File ( targetPath);
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream( file );
        out = new FileOutputStream( destinationFile );
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }

    }finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
}
```

**UploadFile.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags"  prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Upload File Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Select File to Upload</h3>
<s:form action="UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<s:file label="File" name="file"></s:file>
<s:submit value="Upload"></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Struts.xml (part)**

```
<action name="upload">
            <result>/UploadFile.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="UploadFile" class="com.imagramint.appweb.UploadFileAction">
    <param name="filesPath">myfiles</param>
    <result name="success">/UploadFileSuccess.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/UploadFile.jsp</result>

    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">10485760</param>
        <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">text/plain,image/jpeg</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
</action>
```

Now when I tried to upload the file with this scripts python

**Upload.py**

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/Struts2Hibernate/UploadFile.action', files={'file': open('a.jpg', 'rb')})
print r.text
```

I received this error

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.imagramint.appweb.FileUtil.saveFile(FileUtil.java:19)
    com.imagramint.appweb.UploadFileAction.execute(UploadFileAction.java:24)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:325)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 logs.
```

I think the problem could be the form id or name and also the session id but I don't know how to establish in the requests.post.

Perhaps I am completely wrong, and I would need a webservice programmed in struts.

Comment: put some logger to check... 1. url is reached.. of the post request get fired as an inital step to debug. As stated it seems that somewhere somthing is null...you have to trace that!!

Comment: I realized that File is null. But I don't get it, I add some payload and I can receive data in struts and print. Therefore I assume that python script is sending at least the payload ok. And even the negotiation is good, because I realized that python don't need the name, id or session form. Second, I thought could be the file size or even the file type. But using the same image I could upload by jsp form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the python script itself. I have a file input field in struts called "file". So when I ran

```
files = {'file': open('perro.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/Struts2Hibernate/UploadFile.action', files=files, data=datos,cookies=cookie)
```

it seems that variable "files" is a dictionary that contains a file called "file". For some reason, I still don't know why, struts doesn't match that variable with the file input file called "file". That is why the file object was always null.

Because I only used Python to test my Java code, I really don't needed. So I tried with Curl

```
curl -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -F "file=@/home/a.JPG" localhost:8080/Struts2Hibernate/UploadFile.action
```

which it has a field called "file" and I finally could upload the file.

Thank you.